# How do I trigger a Discord bot to write something in the chat?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to get my Discord bot to send a message in the server if someone sends "kris".

I'm using Discord.js v14.

Below is my current code.

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
  console.log(message);

  if (message.author.bot) return;

  if (message.content.toLowerCase() === "kris") {
    message.channel.send("what");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is using the `message` event, which was changed to `messageCreate` in v13.

[Source](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#naming-conventions)

[Docs](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageCreate)

Try this instead:

```js
client.on("messageCreate", message => {
    console.log(message)
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.content.toLowerCase() === 'kris') {
        message.channel.send('what')
    }
    // else if...
});
```

Comment: I'm trying this it is still won't work for me. I don't know why.

Comment: Is your bot appearing online? Try adding this and see what happens:
```client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(\`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!\`);
});```

Comment: yes it is online

Comment: wait, IT'S WORK IN server but not on DM

Comment: It should work as a DM as long as you are messaging the bot. The bot cannot view private DMs since the Discord API doesn't allow that

Comment: okay that's make sense and thanks you for guiding and helping me!

Comment: You need `GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages` for bot to see DMs